# C# interprocess 'broadcast'

Tags: c#, inter-process-communicat

I have 14 different web applications running in IIS, and 4 NT (Windows) services. All of these apps are written in c#. Typically, they would run on one server.

If the user makes a certain change in app 1, i want to notify all the rest of my applications of this.

After looking around, my options are really:

1. WCF host inside each of my apps using named pipes.
2. .net remoting via tcp

I can't use `WM_COPYDATA` because these apps don't have window handles.

I have tried WCF host inside apps, but it seems to slow down app pool creation in IIS; and more importantly, if the app domain is killed by the admin, it takes several seconds before it can be recreated as the service is still registered.

This concerns me with such overhead.

With .Net remoting, it seems i can't use anonymous pipes as i'd need a handle passed from each process to app1 (or vice versa).

With named pipes, it concerns me that i have to register each app on some port (not to mention that i'd have to listen on that via a singleton inside each app pool, which can then have multiple worker processes).

Ideally, i would be looking for something like Android OS 'broadcasts'.

What would be a good solution for such 'event' IPC on one server?

Comment: How critical is this? Will your services fail to behave correctly if the notification fail?

Comment: Have you tried MSMQ?

Comment: If everything is happening on one server and only running apps and services have to be notified then perhaps constructs like [System.Threading.Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) might help, but they're a pretty low level of abstraction.  The One Code [Use shared memory for IPC in C#](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSFileMappingServer-1ec32972) sample from 2013 might be useful.

Comment: @tia, No, they will not

Comment: @PeterKalef'DidiSoft MSMQ is an external dependency, i can not add it (else i could look at nservicebus and the like)

Comment: @FrankBoyne Yes, the problem with both approaches you've suggested is that it allows synchronization cross process, but not notification. E.g. one would need to build a book keeper thread to keep constantly checking the protected area for changes. Doesn't feel elegant.

Comment: @zaitsman, how did you solve this? Im looking at a simulator problem and need some solution.

Comment: @MarkusKnappenJohansson in the end this was not solved, we just agreed that there will be a delay of up to X seconds for updates and had periodic refetch of data at the source. Wasn't the best, but the process in question was rare enough that this didn't matter, and admin could always `iisreset` to kill them all.

For the other application I have used SQL Server Service Broker which can notify you of changes, but it is a very Microsoft specific tech so you need to weigh pros and cons